# Determining the range of values returned by Python's hash()

Tags: python, hash

I would like to map values returned by Python's `hash()` function to floats in the range 0 to 1. On my system I can do this with

```
scale = 1.0/(2**64)
print hash(some_object)*scale+0.5
```

However, I know this will be different on 32-bit systems. Most likely I will never run this code anywhere else, but still I would like to know if there's a way to programmatically determine the maximum and minimum values that Python's built-in `hash()` function can return.

<sub>(By the way the reason I'm doing this is that I'm developing a numerical simulation in which I need to consistently generate the same pseudo-random number from a given Numpy array. I know the built-in hash won't have the best statistics for this, but it's fast, so it's convenient to use it for testing purposes.)</sub>

Comment: I have no answer to your question regarding `hash()` (I'm sure the implementation should tell you everything) however, just for you info: pseudo-random number generators should definitely always return the same result(s) for a given seed, regardless on which system you execute them. So just stick with a pseudo-random implementation and use the same seed for comparison results.

Comment: @septi sure, I can do that, but using the Numpy random number generator it's about 7 times slower than using the built-in hash. (I'm also not sure the statistics will be great, since random number generators aren't designed to be re-seeded every time you use them - but that's another story. They're still likely to be better than the statistics of `hash()` of course.)

Comment: Hmm well, if speed is your main problem, what about reading the implementation of `hash()` and reimplement it so it's not system specific? I'm sure it only has a few lines of code ;-) But beware: as far as I know, `hash` has different implementations for different kind of objects…

Comment: @septi I expect that `hash()` is part of the C implementation, since it's important for the speed of almost everything in Python - but I'm not actually sure how to find out. If I go to the trouble of implementing it myself, I'll use a hash function with better statistics, such as murmurhash. I was mostly asking this question out of curiosity - it seems strange to me that Python doesn't seem to have any kind of hash_max constant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python 2.7 `hash()` returns an `int`, so `sys.maxint` should give you an idea of its range.

Comment: @pts I'm leaving your edit as is, but note that the 2.x documentation refers to `int` as integer almost everywhere

Comment: Warning: Python `hash(x)` does NOT use the full range up to `2**64-1` for inputs `x` of type `int`. At least as of Python 3.6, it appears the result is `(abs(x) % m) * (-1 if x<0 else 1)` with `m=2**61-1`, the 9th Mersenne prime.

Comment: Please consult jlh's answer using `sys.hash_info.width` which seems a much better approach than making assumptions about the relationship between hash width, int width or (Python3) the maximum size of lists.

Comment: `hash()` is not suitable for the purpose of consistently generating the same pseudo-random numbers. Python doesn't guarantee reproducibility and in fact from Python 3.3 `hash()` is randomised (salted) at startup. Check fjarri's answer or do your own hashing, e.g. using `hashlib`.

Answer (score 6):

Python >= 3.2 has [`sys.hash_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.hash_info) which returns a named tuple that contains a key `width` with the bit-width of hash values.  Example: (line breaks added for readability)

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.hash_info
sys.hash_info(
    width=64,
    modulus=2305843009213693951,
    inf=314159,
    nan=0,
    imag=1000003,
    algorithm='siphash24',
    hash_bits=64,
    seed_bits=128,
    cutoff=0
)
```

As shown, Python on my machine uses 64-bit hashes.

Note that if a class implements `__hash__()` but returns an integer beyond this bit width, [it will simply be truncated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash).

Comment: The width can be accessed as `sys.hash_info.width`.

Comment: To support both platforms with signed and unsigned hash, you could use `hash(x) % 2**sys.hash_info.width`, inspired by @falsetru's answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766535/positive-integer-from-python-hash-function

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer to your main question, but an answer to your fine print. `numpy` RNG takes `numpy` arrays as seeds (hashing them internally):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.arange(1000)
>>> b = a.copy()
>>> b[-1] = 0
>>> r1 = numpy.random.RandomState(a)
>>> r2 = numpy.random.RandomState(b)
>>> r3 = numpy.random.RandomState(a)
>>> r1.rand()
0.9343370187421804
>>> r3.rand()
0.9343370187421804
>>> r2.rand()
0.4651506189783071
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of this - it's a fair bit slower than `hash()`, though, so I'm using `hash()` for testing purposes. I'm also not really sure how good the statistics will be when using `numpy.random` this way, since I'll only be generating one random number per input array, and whether this will work well or not is very dependent on how the inputs are hashed - unfortunately the numpy documentation doesn't give much of a clue about it.

Comment: Well, you can always look at [the source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/initarray.c) (see ``init_by_array``). It's written in C and the code looks effective (only a lot of arithmetic operations, no Python interop or suchlike), so it's strange that you find it slow. Is it possible that it's doing the hashing "right", while your algorithm is not 100% reliable?

Comment: yes, it's absolutely the case that `hash()` is unreliable. I am only using it for testing, because it is fast. The numpy method is not unacceptably slow, it's just that `hash()` is about 7 times faster than it. Once I'm running the code for real I will use a proper hash function. Unfortunately I can't tell by looking whether code like `mt[i] = (mt[i] ^ ((mt[i - 1] ^ (mt[i - 1] >> 30)) * 1664525UL)) + init_key[j] + j;` is suitable for any given purpose - the only way is to test it.

Answer (score 1):

`hash()` calls the [`__hash__` hook](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) on the object passed in. That hook *should* return an integer.

Because Python `int` are only limited in size by memory, theoretically there is no real upper limit to the values that `hash()` can return.

If you want to trace how Python objects implement this, search for the `tp_hash` slot in the [`Objects/` directory](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/), or look for the `PyObject_Hash` function calls to see how the value of those slots is used by sets and  dictionaries and other code.

CPython long integer objects themselves limit the return value to a C long int.

Interally, the CPython `type` `tp_hash` function will cast any value returned from a Python `__hash__` function that is greater that falls outside the range for a C long int to the Python long int hash for that value; so a hash value greater than `sys.maxint` will be transformed by calling `hash()` on that value *again*.

So in practice, `hash()` *should* return values limited to `sys.maxint`.

In Python 3, a new type was introduced, `Py_hash_t`; C long is, on some 64-bit platforms, still limited to only 32 bits, but `Py_hash_t` is the same size as a pointer, giving you 64 bits on any 64-bit platform. On Python 3, the `sys.maxsize` value reflects the maximum correctly; it returns the maximum value a pointer on your platform can hold.