# Generate unique IDs for a list of strings with duplicates

Tags: python, list, uniqueidentifier

I want to generate IDs for strings that are being read from a text file. If the strings are duplicates, I want the first instance of the string to have an ID containing 6 characters. For the duplicates of that string, I want the ID to be the same as the original one, but with an additional two characters. I'm having trouble with the logic. Here's what I've done so far:

```
from itertools import groupby
import uuid
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
addresses = f.readlines()

list_of_addresses = ['Address']
list_of_ids = ['ID']


for x in addresses:
    list_of_addresses.append(x)


def find_duplicates():

    for x, y in groupby(sorted(list_of_addresses)):
        id = str(uuid.uuid4().get_hex().upper()[0:6])
        j = len(list(y))
        if j > 1:
            print str(j) + " instances of " + x
            list_of_ids.append(id)
        print list_of_ids

find_duplicates()
```

How should I approach this?

Edit: here's the contents of `test.txt`:

```
123 Test
123 Test
123 Test
321 Test
567 Test
567 Test
```

And the output:

```
3 occurences of 123 Test

['ID', 'C10DD8']
['ID', 'C10DD8']
2 occurences of 567 Test

['ID', 'C10DD8', '595C5E']
['ID', 'C10DD8', '595C5E']
```

Comment: Please give sample inputs and expected outputs

Comment: And by repeated "strings" do you mean repeated lines repeated words in a line?

Comment: @pylang Sorry, added input/output. And I mean duplicate text entries.

Comment: Take look at your output again.  You are missing `321` and your ids are the same for your duplicates.  You mentioned adding two more characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the strings are duplicates, I want the first instance of the string to have an ID containing 6 characters. For the duplicates of that string, I want the ID to be the same as the original one, but with an additional two characters.

Try using a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

**Given**

```
import ctypes
import collections as ct


filename = "test.txt"


def read_file(fname):
    """Read lines from a file."""
    with open(fname, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.strip()
```

**Code**

```
dd = ct.defaultdict(list)
for x in read_file(filename):
    key = str(ctypes.c_size_t(hash(x)).value)      # make positive hashes
    if key[:6] not in dd:
        dd[key[:6]].append(x)
    else:
        dd[key[:8]].append(x)

dd
```

Output

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'133259': ['123 Test'],
             '13325942': ['123 Test', '123 Test'],
             '210763': ['567 Test'],
             '21076377': ['567 Test'],
             '240895': ['321 Test']})
```

The resulting dictionary has keys (of length 6) for every first occurrence of a unique line. For every successive replicate line, two additional characters are sliced for the key.

You can implement the keys however you wish.  In this case, we used `hash()` to correlate the key to each unique line.  We then sliced the desired sequence from the key.  See also a post on making [positive hash values from `ctypes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766535/positive-integer-from-python-hash-function).

---

To inspect your results, create the appropriate lookup dictionaries from the `defaultdict`.

```
# Lookups 
occurrences = ct.defaultdict(int)
ids = ct.defaultdict(list)

for k, v in dd.items():
    key = v[0]
    occurrences[key] += len(v)
    ids[key].append(k)

# View data
for k, v in occurrences.items():
    print("{} instances of {}".format(v, k))
    print("IDs:", ids[k])
    print()
```

Output

```
1 instances of 321 Test
IDs: ['240895']

2 instances of 567 Test
IDs: ['21076377', '210763']

3 instances of 123 Test
IDs: ['13325942', '133259']
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you for the thorough response.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little confusing, I don't get what is criteria to generate id , here i am showing you just logic not exact solution, You can take help from logic

```
track={}
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line_no,line in enumerate(f):
        if line.split()[0] not in track:
            track[line.split()[0]]=[['ID','your_unique_id']]
        else:
            #here put your logic what you want to append if id is dublicate
            track[line.split()[0]].append(['ID','dublicate_id'+str(line_no)])

print(track)
```

output:

```
{'123': [['ID', 'your_unique_id'], ['ID', 'dublicate_id1'], ['ID', 'dublicate_id2']], '321': [['ID', 'your_unique_id']], '567': [['ID', 'your_unique_id'], ['ID', 'dublicate_id5']]}
```